# iPhone basic sheet programming?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwindow

I want to program an "Add"-Window to my application, much like the "Add Contact"-window in the Contacts app or the "Add City"-window in the Weather app.

My question is: how do I code the effect of sliding up that Contacts & Weather feature?

-- Ry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called "modal view controllers".

You create a view controller for that "sheet", and from any method of another view controller call

```
sheetViewController = [[SheetViewController alloc] init…]
[self presentModalViewController:sheetViewController animated:YES];
```

to slide up the sheet, and from any method of the sheet view controller call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to slide down. Search the term "Modal View Controllers" in the Xcode docs for detail.